# differnce between .csv file an Excel sheet in My sql database

Tags: mysql

what is the advantage of using excel sheet over .csv file while exporting data to database...plz share the differnces and which format is best to load data to database.
  I want to load bulcks of data and and tabels to database.
waht is the solution for this

Comment: `csv` stands for `comma seperated values`. When you import a csv file it can accurately format it. Also, csv is much lighter

Comment: And have you already done some research which you can mention with your question?